# Angularjs dynamic looping to access dynamic values of array keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am generating following json data from my database where keys like `sid` and `name` is `static` but `task1`,`task2`,`task3` .... are `dynamic` and they can be upto value n(where n=1,2,3......)

My data:

```
  [
    {"sid":"10","name":"nam1","task1" :"1","task2" :"0","task3" :"1","task4" :"0","task5" :"0"},

    {"sid":"20","name":"nam2","task1" :"0","task2" :"1","task3" :"0","task4" :"1","task5" :"1"},

    {"sid":"30","name":"nam3","task1" :"1","task2" :"1","task3" :"0","task4" :"0","task5" :"1"},

    {"sid":"40","name":"nam4","task1" :"0","task2" :"0","task3" :"0","task4" :"0","task5" :"1"}
    ]
```

app.js

```
app.controller('taskCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('get.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
```

Now i am trying to access key values using `ng-repeat` like below:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="data in list| unique: 'sid'">
       <td>{{data.sid }}</td>
       <td>{{data.name}}</td>
       <td>{{data.task1}}</td>
       <td>{{data.task2}}</td>
       <td>{{data.task3}}</td>
       <td>{{data.task4}}</td>
       <td>{{data.task5}}</td>

   <tr/>
```

The above code works well for fixed keys like task1,task2,task3... but i am generating `"task"` key dynamically so it will be always unknown to me that how many task keys are there.There may be a case when there are keys from task1 to task100 so the above code will fail on that case.

I am trying to dynamically access the task keys to generate associate data.To achieve this i am concatenating a number( produced by an incremental loop)  with the task key so that i becomes like  task1,task2 .... value n

```
 <tr ng-repeat="data in list| unique: 'sid'">
      <td> {{ data.sid }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.name }} </td>
      <td ng-repeat="data in list| limitTo:n">
      {{ id=$index+1; 'data.task'+id}}
      </td>
  </tr>
Id starts with 1 and incremented in every loop  so that we can dynamically  access  data.task1,data.task2 and so on
```

I am  facing two problems here.After concatenation i was supposed to get the value of a corresponding `task key` but i am getting like this `data.task1`,`data.task2`,`data.task3` that is i am getting keys itself instead of key values.

The second problem is i want to loop up to `n` number of times so i am limiting the `ng-repeat` by `n` like this way `ng-repeat="data in list| limitTo:n"` but the value of `n` is unknown to me.Here `n` should be equal to the highest number of dynamic task key(or total task keys).

For example if in the data list there exist `task1`,`task2`,`task3`,`task4`,`task5` then `n` will be 5 since there are total 5 task keys.If there exist task1 to task100 then `n` will be 100 as there are total 100 task keys.

One idea to achieve this could be counting total unique keys from the array and then subtract 2 static keys from it to get the number of dynamic keys which will be used as value of `n` to limit the loop.

For example in above data set the unique keys are `sid`,`name`,`task1`,`task2`,`task3`,`task4`,`task5` if somehow we can manage to calculate total number of unique keys from the array  then the  total number of unique keys will be 7 in this case, and if we subtract 2 from the number 7 then we have 5 which is equal to the number of dynamic keys in the array, that we want to use as `n` to limit the loop.

Any idea how to solve my above problems using angularjs  ?

Comment: This may be overly simplistic, but I'd argue that your general data structure is incorrect. Couldn't your `tasks` be an `Array`? Then this would be an iteration.

Comment: actually i am introducing this type of data structure because it meets my need best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it will work as per your expectation..**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
    {"sid":"10","name":"nam1","task1" :"1","task2" :"0","task3" :"1","task4" :"0","task5" :"0"},

    {"sid":"20","name":"nam2","task1" :"0","task2" :"1","task3" :"0","task4" :"1","task5" :"1"},

    {"sid":"30","name":"nam3","task1" :"1","task2" :"1","task3" :"0","task4" :"0","task5" :"1"},

    {"sid":"40","name":"nam4","task1" :"0","task2" :"0","task3" :"0","task4" :"0","task5" :"1"}
    ];

for (var i in $scope.list) {
  var res = Object.keys($scope.list[i]).filter(item => { return item.indexOf("task") > -1; });
  $scope.tasksList = res;
}
    
});
```

```css
table,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="data in list">
      <td> {{ data.sid }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.name }} </td>
      <td ng-repeat="item in tasksList"> {{ data[item] }} </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the total number of `task` attributes on an Item may be varied.

By returning the list of Keys which start with *Task* you can iterate over that list instead and making it a function, you can call that during each iteration of `ngRepeat`:

```
 $scope.getTaskKeys = function(row) {
    return Object.keys(row).filter(function(keyname) {
       return keyname.startsWith('task');
 });
```

Leaving you free to call it as the collection for the second iteration:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="data in list| unique: 'sid'">
      <td> {{ data.sid }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.name }} </td>
      <td ng-repeat="taskKey in getTaskKeys(data)">
      {{data[taskKey]}}
      </td>
 </tr>
```

Created a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/zd1yjc0m/

Answer (score 0):

data[0] contain the JSON data and data[1] contain dynamic key

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data[0] ">
        <td ng-repeat="j in data[1]">
        [[ x[j] ]] 
        </td>
 </tr>
```